# Trading Partner uses VAN, do I mandatorily need to use a VAN as well?

Tags: edi

As expressed in the title, one of our trading partner is using a VAN (Value Added Network) and we are wondering if we mandatorily need to use a VAN as well to exchange with him?

Why can't we use our own API management/gateway platform to communicate with him?

We basically want to centralize all our communications through one unique API platform and avoid using VANs.

As our partners are using them, I want to know if, generally speaking, every VAN allows direct communication with the partners account in that VAN coming from the outside? Or does it always need to be coming from our own account within that VAN, forcing us to use one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your partner uses a VAN, then you need to retrieve the data from the VAN.  The VANs don't care about your APIs and likely won't attempt to integrate with it.  The communication protocols in place (FTP, AS2, SFTP, etc) serve pretty much everyone.  You won't need an account to connect to the VAN.

Find out what VAN your partner is using and then set up a connection to them using their supported protocols.  For example, you'll want to support AS2.  Your partner will send data to the VAN, and the VAN will route it and push it directly to you.

Most VANs these days act like clearing houses, and many of them do translation as a SaaS offering.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I just got confused reading your answer. What do you mean by "The VANs don't care about your APIs and likely won't attempt to integrate with it" and then "our partner will send data to the VAN, and the VAN will route it and push it directly to you."
This for me kind of contradicts but I guess I am not understanding what you mean.
My underlying question is if a VAN from customer would actually accept to send and receive transactions to my own integration endpoints  without needing to have my own account on that VAN?

Comment: As long as the endpoint is a protocol the VAN already supports.  That's what I was driving at.  The VAN isn't likely to use your API.

Comment: I see so you are specifically speaking about the API protocol. Indeed, our Integration Platform for B2B handles a variety of Protocols to actually accommodate for this. I guess this means we should be fine to communicate back and forth with the customer's VAN right? I was basically worried that there are commercial constraints to force you to onboard as well within that VAN and create an account on it to be able to communicate with your trading partner's account.

Comment: Yes - If you're able to connect to the VAN using FTP/SFTP or establish an AS2 connection, you should be good to go.  For example, I communicate with the OpenText VAN via AS2, but I do not pay OpenText for a mailbox or the connection. Hope this helps.